# Avoid to use $watch when directive attribute changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive `<resized-image>` which has an attribute `id`. Based on this id it asks an API for an image object.

This directive is used as an header image for an article. In order to know the `id`, the data of the article needs to be loaded first.

So when the article loading is completed, the `id` of the `<resized-image>` is set and it can start loading the image.

The only way I can solve this is by using a `$watch` inside the directive on the `id` property.

Is there another cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngIf:

```
<resized-image id=myId ng-if=myId></resized-image>
```

resizedImage will be compiled when myId has a value

Answer (score 2):

You are right in the fact that you should avoid using watches. But when they are used, be sure to make them as efficient and limited as possible.

I suggest reading the following article with many effective alternative strategies: https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/effective-strategies-avoiding-watches-angularjs/

The 5 alternatives he talks about are:

1. $scope Communication
2. ngModel $parsers
3. ngModel $viewChangeListeners
4. setInterval
5. filters